# override a linq attribute c#

Tags: c#, linq

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Gender", DbType="Int NOT NULL", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
public int Gender
{
    get
    {
        return this._Gender;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._Gender != value))
        {
            this.OnGenderChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._Gender = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("Gender");
            this.OnGenderChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

there is an attribute for `update check` which I set it to `never`. But when ever I made a small change in dbml I must set this property of this field to never again. How can I override this attribute for ever in an partial class?

Update: as an example I can change dbml connection string like this, one time for ever:

```
partial class DataBaseDataContext : System.Data.Linq.DataContext
{
    public DataBaseDataContext() :
        base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ToString())
    {
        OnCreated();
    }
}
```

Comment: Question. why are you using Linq2Sql for your project? That system has been fairly abandoned by Microsoft in favor of Entity Framework instead.

Comment: the diagram I think is the SAME in entity and linq, isn't?

Comment: I don't know, I never use dbml files with EF, I only ever use Code First.

Comment: @Nofuzy, the diagram looks similar but under the hood, LINQ to SQL uses dbml and LINQ to Entities uses an .edmx file.

Answer (score 2):

Open the dbml file in the designer and set `Update Check` for the property to the desired value. Don't modify the generated files directly, it will be overwritten.

[image]

Comment: sometimes I add a table to database or modify it and I need to rebuild a new dbml design, but some parts are the same and I must always set their update check to never. I need to override it one time for ever, I add an example to my question.